# How do I import flipkart products from a csv into Wordpress/WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, woocommerce, flipkart-api

I have a csv from flipkart with fields such as:

`productId` `title` `description` `mrp` `price` `productUrl` `categories`

Obviously these don't match up perfectly with the WooCommerce fields ( short description / long description vs description ), `productId` vs `sku` but does anyone have tips on how to go about matching these up to be compatible with WooCommerce, or can recommend any WP plugins that may do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce product is also a custom post type (product) only. you can easily write your own custom importer.

Each product may have the following structure

```
product - parent post
   -- attachment - featured image, gallery
   -- product meta - options, category, tags, price, stock ...
   -- variation - product variants (it also contains options, price, stock...)
```

the importer flow will be like

```
createProduct() {}
uploadImages() {}
createProductMeta() {}
createProductVariants() {}
```

Woocommerce already has all the necessory codes you want, refer `WP_PLUGIN/woocommerce/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php`

```
create_product( $data ) - line number 174
save_product_images( $id, $images ) - line number 1551
save_product_meta( $id, $data ) - line number 638
save_variations( $id, $data ) - line number 1080
```

trust me it's easy, i have already done that ( not for flipkart but shopify to woocommerce )

Comment: Do you have any advice as to actually starting the import code? I have experience with modifying but not creating plugins. Any links to some articles on that, or just where I'd create the files?

Comment: @meder sent me a sample csv for one product, so that i can modify my existing code ( shopify to woocommerce ) to your needs.

Comment: here you go: http://static.arounds.org/example.csv

Comment: find the sample implementation here http://sarkware.com/fliport.zip

Comment: Cool - thank you so much. Is there any reason you didn't just create say, a cron job to pull from a REST API vs manual csv importing? just no capability for shopify? I'm wondering if I should do the API way for FlipKart

Comment: Also created a new question for pairing products together, not sure if you have any idea but.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711058/how-can-i-group-the-same-products-from-different-merchants-feeds-like-flipkart

Comment: @meder yes you are right, Shopify has REST API, we can pull all products from Shopify ( as json ) and Iterate through Json and prepare Woocommerce product object ( post ) and Insert it ( that's how i did it ).

Comment: @meder I never used cron job, just a normal Apache process enough for that. to import around 1500 products ( each has avg of 60 to 80 variants ) it took 9 hours.

Comment: If flipkart has REST API, go for it, JSON is 100% better that CSV.

Answer (score 0):

For all imports you can use Wordpress **wp_insert_post()** function. You should create basic template for this work. Read data files with lines. And foreach it. While **foreach**ing, define title, content or other fields.

Comment: But wouldn't I have to use something that inserts products, not posts? Or are products at the root still posts? Like I'd want to define fields for price, etc.

Comment: Could you convert your csv to array with php?