# Wordpress Woocommerce new product hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a hook for creating a new product for Woocommerce, I would like to create one product and distribute it to all my multi sites on one create

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682179/how-do-i-import-flipkart-products-from-a-csv-into-wordpress-woocommerce/27691316#27691316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use this plugin to accomplish what you're hoping

http://plugins.plainview.se/threewp-broadcast-premium-pack/

There isn't a hook to do it programmatically that I'm aware of. You could look at the code that the free version of the plugin uses and attempt to manipulate it to work for "products" instead of "posts".

https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/